# Are Chromium addons and UFW Firewall settings set for all users?

Tags: networking, security, users, firewall, ufw

Are things such as Chromium addons and UFW Firewall settings automatically set for all users and future users on Linux distributions ?

Comment: Those are wholly different things.  The firewall controls the entire system so obviously it applies to all users.  An add-on can be installed in a number of different ways, some of which are single-user only.

Comment: @tripleee Indeed they are different things, I was just wondering about the settings for both, even if they are unrelated, they could affect in common the creation of new users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall, and more generally the network configuration, is a system setting. It applies to all users. Creating new user accounts doesn't change the system settings (apart from the accounts, of course).

Note that a web proxy setting is a user setting, because it's applied by each browser, not by the system.

Chromium add-ons are installed as part of a Chromium profile (the same goes for other browsers: Chrome, Firefox, etc.). Each user has their own browser profile (and you can even create multiple profiles on your account). It's possible to install system-wide add-ons, but rarely done except in some enterprise setups.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I mainly needed to understand better the difference, you clarified that point.